# Vim doesn't manage buffers properly

Tags: vim

I experience a very weird problem with Vim and buffers (Ubuntu 16.04 / Vim 7.4.1689)

Let's say I have 2 files in my Download folder:

`file1.txt file2.txt`

If I run Vim from my home directory and I open the 2 files through the `:Explore` command 
then I check the buffers

`:ls`

Only the last opened file is in the list, the first one has disapeared.

Now if I run Vim from the Download directory and I open the 2 files through the `:Explore` command then I check the buffers

`:ls`

the 2 files are in the buffer list.

What's the problem here ?

Comment: Can't reproduce this on vim 7.4.1743.

Comment: Do you run Vim on an Ubuntu 16.04 version ? Do you think Vim 7.4.1669 is a buggy version ?

Comment: Vim has an issue tracker. Use it.

Comment: Every version of almost every software is buggy. But as bugs go, this doesn't seem very serious.

Comment: I've just upgraded the netrw plugin to the latest version (157a) and everything seems ok now.